# Abilities hot bar is red and won't work

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I am level 6 and all of a sudden I can't use any of my abilities. When I'm in the battle, the hot bar is red and won't work. I've tried going into character records and changing the abilities around, and checking if everything is enabled and it all looks fine.

All the other characters abilities work fine.

I'm playing on the Xbox 360. Any tips?

Comment: Wrong weapon maybe? There're skills you can't use with every weapon. A warrior for example can't use 2h skills while holding a shield

Answer (score 3):

If you are playing as a Warrior or Rogue your abilities cost Stamina. You will need to build stamina by attacking in order to be able to use your abilities after you have depleted your stamina.

Comment: Your stamina starts out full and depletes when you use abilities. You don't have to initially charge it to use abilities.

Comment: So you do need to attack to be able to constantly use them. Sorry, I will reword my answer.